# Polars: assign existing category

Tags: python-polars

I am using Polars to analyze some A/B test data (and a little bit more...). Now I had to correct for some inconsistency. `df_prep` is a Polars DataFrame that has a column `'Group'` of type `cat` with levels `'A'` and `'B'`.
Naively, I did this:

```py
# After the A/B test period, everything is B!
df_prep = (df_prep.lazy()
           .with_column(
               pl.when(pl.col('Datum') >= pl.col('TestEndDate'))
               .then('B')
               .otherwise(pl.col('Group'))
               .alias('Group'))
           .collect())
```

However, the problem is now that `df_prep['Group'].unique()` gives

```
shape: (3,)
Series: 'Group' [cat]
[
    "B"
    "A"
    "B"
]
```

This is obviously not what I wanted. I wanted to assign the existing category "B".

How could this be achieved?

EDIT: I found one way:

```py
df_prep = df_prep.with_column(pl.col('Group').cast(pl.Utf8).cast(pl.Categorical).alias('Group'))
```

But this doesn't seem right to me... Isn't there a more ideomatic solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem when comparing string values to Categorical values.  One way to solve this problem is to use a string cache, either globally or using a context manager.

##### Without a string cache

First, let's take a closer look at what is occurring.  Let's start with this data, and look at the underlying physical representation of the Categorical variable (the integer that represents each unique category value).

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df_prep = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series(
            name="Group",
            values=["A", "A", "B", "B"],
            dtype=pl.Categorical,
        ),
        pl.Series(
            name="Datum",
            values=pl.date_range(date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 1, 4), "1d"),
        ),
        pl.Series(name="TestEndDate", values=[date(2022, 1, 4)] * 4),
    ]
)

(
    df_prep
    .with_column(pl.col('Group').to_physical().alias('Physical'))
)
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ Group ┆ Datum      ┆ TestEndDate ┆ Physical │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ cat   ┆ date       ┆ date        ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

Note that `A` is a assigned a physical value of `0`; `B`, a value of `1`.

Now, let's run the next step (without a string cache), and see what happens:

```py
result = (
    df_prep.lazy()
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col("Datum") >= pl.col("TestEndDate"))
        .then("B")
        .otherwise(pl.col("Group"))
        .alias("Group")
    )
    .with_column(pl.col('Group').to_physical().alias('Physical'))
    .collect()
)
result
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ Group ┆ Datum      ┆ TestEndDate ┆ Physical │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ cat   ┆ date       ┆ date        ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

Notice what happened.  Without a string cache, the underlying physical representations of the Categorical values have changed.  Indeed, the Categorical value `B` now has two underlying physical representations: `2` and `0`.  Polars sees the two `B`'s as distinct.

Indeed, we see this if we use `unique` on this column:

```py
result.get_column('Group').unique()
```

```
shape: (3,)
Series: 'Group' [cat]
[
        "B"
        "A"
        "B"
]
```

##### Using a global string cache

One easy way to handle this is to use a global string cache while making comparisons between strings and Categorical values, or setting values for Categorical variables using strings.

We'll set the global string cache and rerun the algorithm.  We'll use Polars' [`toggle_string_cache`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.toggle_string_cache.html#polars.toggle_string_cache) method to achieve this.

```py
pl.toggle_string_cache(True)
df_prep = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series(
            name="Group",
            values=["A", "A", "B", "B"],
            dtype=pl.Categorical,
        ),
        pl.Series(
            name="Datum",
            values=pl.date_range(date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 1, 4), "1d"),
        ),
        pl.Series(name="TestEndDate", values=[date(2022, 1, 4)] * 4),
    ]
)

result = (
    df_prep.lazy()
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col("Datum") >= pl.col("TestEndDate"))
        .then("B")
        .otherwise(pl.col("Group"))
        .alias("Group")
    )
    .with_column(pl.col('Group').to_physical().alias('Physical'))
    .collect()
)
result
```

```
>>> result
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ Group ┆ Datum      ┆ TestEndDate ┆ Physical │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ cat   ┆ date       ┆ date        ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

```
>>> result.get_column('Group').unique()
shape: (2,)
Series: 'Group' [cat]
[
        "A"
        "B"
]
```

Notice how the Categorical variable maintains its correct physical representation.  And the results of using `unique` on `Group` are what we expect.

##### Using a Context Manager

If you don't want to keep a global string cache in effect, you can use a context manager to set a localized, temporary [`StringCache`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.StringCache.html#polars.StringCache) while you are making comparisons to strings.

```py
with pl.StringCache():
    df_prep = pl.DataFrame(
        [
            pl.Series(
                name="Group",
                values=["A", "A", "B", "B"],
                dtype=pl.Categorical,
            ),
            pl.Series(
                name="Datum",
                values=pl.date_range(date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 1, 4), "1d"),
            ),
            pl.Series(name="TestEndDate", values=[date(2022, 1, 4)] * 4),
        ]
    )

    result = (
        df_prep.lazy()
        .with_column(
            pl.when(pl.col("Datum") >= pl.col("TestEndDate"))
            .then("B")
            .otherwise(pl.col("Group"))
            .alias("Group")
        )
        .with_column(pl.col('Group').to_physical().alias('Physical'))
        .collect()
    )
    result
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ Group ┆ Datum      ┆ TestEndDate ┆ Physical │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ cat   ┆ date       ┆ date        ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

```
>>> result.get_column('Group').unique()
shape: (2,)
Series: 'Group' [cat]
[
        "A"
        "B"
]
```

##### Edit: Reading/Scanning external files

You can read/scan external files with a string cache in effect.  For example, below I've saved our DataFrame to `tmp.parquet`.

If I use `read_parquet` with a string cache in effect, the Categorical variables are included in the string cache.

(Note: in the examples below, I'll use a Context Manager -- to clearly delineate where the string cache is in effect.)

```py
import polars as pl
with pl.StringCache():
    (
        pl.read_parquet('tmp.parquet')
        .with_column(
            pl.when(pl.col("Datum") >= pl.col("TestEndDate"))
            .then("B")
            .otherwise(pl.col("Group"))
            .alias("Group")
        )
        .with_column(pl.col('Group').to_physical().alias('Physical'))
    )
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ Group ┆ Datum      ┆ TestEndDate ┆ Physical │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ cat   ┆ date       ┆ date        ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

Notice that our Categorical values are correct.  (The `B` values have the same underlying physical representation.)

However, if we move the `read_parquet` method outside the Context Manager (so that the DataFrame is created without a string cache), we have a problem.

```py
df_prep = pl.read_parquet('tmp.parquet')

with pl.StringCache():
    (
        df_prep
        .with_column(
            pl.when(pl.col("Datum") >= pl.col("TestEndDate"))
            .then("B")
            .otherwise(pl.col("Group"))
            .alias("Group")
        )
        .with_column(pl.col('Group').to_physical().alias('Physical'))
    )
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/StackOverflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py", line 4027, in with_column
    self.lazy()
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/StackOverflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 803, in collect
    return pli.wrap_df(ldf.collect())
exceptions.ComputeError: cannot combine categorical under a global string cache with a non cached categorical
```

The error message says it all.

##### Edit: Placing existing Categorical columns under a string cache

One way to correct the situation above (assuming that it's already too late to re-read your DataFrame with a string cache) is to put a new string cache into effect, and then cast the values back to strings and then back to Categorical.

Below, we'll use a shortcut to perform this for all Categorical columns in parallel - by specifying `pl.Categorical` in the `pl.col`.

```py
with pl.StringCache():
    (
        df_prep
        .with_columns([
            pl.col(pl.Categorical).cast(pl.Utf8).cast(pl.Categorical)
        ])
        .with_column(
            pl.when(pl.col("Datum") >= pl.col("TestEndDate"))
            .then("B")
            .otherwise(pl.col("Group"))
            .alias("Group")
        )
        .with_column(pl.col('Group').to_physical().alias('Physical'))
    )
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ Group ┆ Datum      ┆ TestEndDate ┆ Physical │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ cat   ┆ date       ┆ date        ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B     ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-01-04  ┆ 1        │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

And now our code works correctly again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to clarify: This means that the string cache, using either of the two ways, has to be in place before the column “Group” is created. Otherwise there is no way? Say, if I read the data from a parquet file and it’s already “cat”. Or say I want to filter from a Categorical column with a level value that a user selects from a Dropdown in a Dash app, so I only have its string value… In that case there is only the option to cast? Is there no way to load all existing levels into a string cache? Also, there is no way to use e.g. pl.lit and make clear that I mean an existing level?

Comment: Sorry, the second example is not really a reason… but in the first case?

Comment: Oops, I should have been more clear about when the string cache needs to be in effect.  I've edited the answer - and also included discussion of reading external files under a string cache.